# FullCalendar - How to show event based upon comma separated dates from database(mysql) table row on calendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, wordpress

I am trying to show multiple events based upon dates from the same row of the table in the database separated by commas as show in picture:

[Image from the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOuEf.png)

This is the my php/wordpress code that fetch the result from database:

```
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <?php
            $title = get_the_title();
            //$date = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trainee_date_pick', true));
            $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trainee_date_pick', true);
            //$dateArray = explode(',', $date);
            $mealdes = nl2br(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meal_plan_des', true));
            $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube_videos', true);
            $url_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube_videos_sec', true);
            $meal_lable = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meal_plan_label', true);
            $array_cal[$i]["title"] = $title;
            $array_cal[$i]["start"] = $date;
            $array_cal[$i]["url"] = $url;
            $array_cal[$i]["urltwo"] = $url_two;
            $array_cal[$i]["description"] = $mealdes;
            $array_cal[$i]["meallable"] = do_shortcode("[nutrition-label id=" . $meal_lable . "]");
            $i++;
            ?>
            <?php
        endwhile;
}
echo json_encode($array_cal);
?>
```

After searching I try it doing myself, above code return the json like this but didn't show anything on the calendar but when there is single date it showed up.

```
[{"title":"Full Body","start":"2015-12-09, 2015-12-31","url":"","urltwo":"","description":"Deadlift 5x5
\r\nPause Squats 3x8
\r\nBench Press 3x8
\r\nClose Grip Bench 3x12
\r\nAlternating Curls 3x12
\r\nDips 3xMax
\r\nJump Rope 20 minutes
\r\n","meallable":""}]
```

And this is the jQuery code where I read json array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            events: "/calendar-events/",
            eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.attr('href', 'javascript:void(0);');
            element.click(function () {
            jQuery("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
                    jQuery("#eventInfo").html(event.description);
                    jQuery("#eventLink").attr('href', event.url);
                    jQuery("#eventLink2").attr('href', event.urltwo);
                    jQuery("#meal_label").html(event.meallable);
//                    jQuery("#labeledit").attr('href',event.editlab);
//                    jQuery('#eventedit').attr('href',event.eventedit);
           jQuery("#eventContent").dialog({modal: true, title: event.title, width: 350});
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I really need help please somebody come up the solution.

Comment: The only thing I can really see is that in your JSON, the `start` is malformed. From what I can see, it seems that your start has two dates in it, the beginning and the end, so you should split those and send the end parameter to the json as well and see if that may help. [Event Object](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) and check out the links for the `ISO8601 string` that is required. Other than that, I can't see much wrong with it.

Comment: No, jon they both are start dates I want to show single event on multiple dates.

Comment: Do both days show up correctly on full calendar when you pass just that one event?

Comment: No that's what I am asking its not showing with both dates when like this (2015-12-09, 2015-12-31) but when there is single date (2015-12-31) it showed up on calendar.

Comment: Is there a max of two dates in there, or can there be more?

Comment: Yes, there I'll be more with no limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that I understand your problem... It's just a matter of going through the list of dates for each event that may have multiple.  For this, going to un-comment one of your lines, and add two more. It will look something like this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <?php
        $title = get_the_title();
        //$date = explode(',',get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trainee_date_pick', true));
        $date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trainee_date_pick', true);
        $dateArray = explode(',', $date);
        $mealdes = nl2br(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meal_plan_des', true));
        $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube_videos', true);
        $url_two = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'youtube_videos_sec', true);
        $meal_lable = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meal_plan_label', true);
        foreach($dateArray as $date) {
            $array_cal[$i]["title"] = $title;
            $array_cal[$i]["start"] = trim($date);
            $array_cal[$i]["url"] = $url;
            $array_cal[$i]["urltwo"] = $url_two;
            $array_cal[$i]["description"] = $mealdes;
            $array_cal[$i]["meallable"] = do_shortcode("[nutrition-label id=" . $meal_lable . "]");
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
        <?php
    endwhile;
}
echo json_encode($array_cal);
?>
```